# Call DhcpGetClientInfo in 64bit process fails

Tags: .net, 64-bit, pinvoke, 32-bit

I am trying to do a call to [DhcpGetClientInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  in a .net process compiled as 64bit.

```
[DllImport(@"dhcpsapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern UInt32 DhcpGetClientInfo(
    String ServerIpAddress,
    ref DHCP_SEARCH_INFO SearchInfo,
    out IntPtr ClientInfo);
```

Some points to note

- When the process is compiled as 32 bit it works.
- The error code returned is 20013. Which according to the [error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is "An error occurred while accessing the DHCP JET database. For more information about this error, please look at the DHCP server event log." However there is nothing in the event log on the server. I also ensured all the DHCP specific logs were enabled and nothing appeared there either.

Comment: can we see how you are marshaling the fields in DHCP_SEARCH_INFO?

Comment: since union should be kinda like below.[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ClientSearchInfo
{
 [FieldOffset(0)]
 public int SearchType;

 [FieldOffset(4)]
 public IntPtr ClientIpAddress;

 [FieldOffset(4)]
 public IntPtr ClientHardwareAddress;

 [FieldOffset(4)]
 public IntPtr ClientName;
}

or could just do 

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ClientSearchInfo
{
 [FieldOffset(0)]
 public int SearchType;

 [FieldOffset(4)]
 public IntPtr SearchValue;

}

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is the use of UInt32.  Incidentally, I believe is UInt32 is deprecated (non-CLS compliant).